# syntax error near unexpected token `(' when using multiple input streams from zcat in Python subprocess

Tags: bash, python-3.x, inputstream, zcat

I ran this in Python 3.5:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(
    'some_command --option <(zcat some_file_1.gz) <(zcat some_file_2.gz)', 
    shell=True
)
```

Got this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: process substitution using `<(...)` is not defined in POSIX. you should use something like bash.

Answer (score 5):

Process substitution using `<(...)` is not defined in POSIX. you should use something like bash.
You can pass `executable="/bin/bash"` to run the command using bash.

```
subprocess.run('cat <(echo hoo)', shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

Answer (score 2):

The default shell being invoked is `/bin/sh` and it does not support [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) (the `<(...)` syntax), which is a Bash feature.